# What does ∀x¬∃xQ(x,x)

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I got two questions. I am supposed to convert logical forms into prenex normal form, and haveing troubles with two forms.

Firstly
What does ∀x¬∃xQ(x,x) ∨ ∃xS(x) means?. I believe I cannot just call one of the first two a "y", since I don't know if Q() symmetric is. But can I call the last x a y? and How to interpret the first part?

and secondly how to interpret this:
¬∀x¬∀y(Q(x,y)→¬∃yS(y))

can I think of it as

```
                                          ⟺¬∀x(¬∀y(Q(x,y)→¬∃yS(y))) 
                                          ⟺ ∃x¬{¬∀y(Q(x,y) → ¬∃wS(w))}
                                          ⟺ ∃x¬{¬∀y(Q(x,y) → ¬∃wS(w))}
                                          ⟺ ∃x¬{¬∀y(¬Q(x,y) ∨ ¬∃wS(w))}
                                          ⟺ ∃x{∀y(Q(x,y) ∧ ¬∃wS(w))}
```

or

```
                                          ⟺¬∀x¬∀y(Q(x,y)→¬∃yS(y))
                                          ⟺ ∃x¬∀y¬(Q(x,y)→¬∃yS(y))
                                          ⟺ ∃x∃y(Q(x,y)→¬∃yS(y))
                                          ⟺ ∃x∃y(Q(x,y)→¬∃wS(w))
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Comment: $∀x¬∃xQ(x,x)$ means that there is **no** $x$ such that $Q(x,x)$. Example with *numbers* :  $¬∃n ( n < n)$.

Comment: What if it was ∃x¬∀xQ(x,x), would it mean then ¬∀xQ(x,x)?

Comment: Exactly; a quantifier that quantify a variable that is not *free* has no effect. In formal terms : if $x$ is not *free* in $\varphi$, then $\forall x \varphi \equiv \varphi$, and the same for $\exists$.

Comment: Both of them to be converted into prenex form. Seperate questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\forall x \neg \exists x Q(x,x)$, the first quantifier is called a 'Null quantifier': it effectively quantifies nothing at all, since the $x$'s in $Q(x,x)$ are quantified by the $\exists x$

So, this statement is simply equivalent to $\neg \exists x Q(x,x)$ ... and its prenex normal thus $\forall x \neg Q(x,x)$

In $\neg \forall x \neg \forall y (Q(x,y) \rightarrow \neg \exists y \ S(y))$, the $y$ in $S(y)$ is quantified by the $\exists y$, and therefore not by the $\forall y$. The $\forall y$ does quantifiy the $y$ in $Q(x,y)$ though, so it is not a null quantifier. In such a case, it's best to replace the duplicate variable with a new variable,e.g:

$\neg \forall x \neg \forall y (Q(x,y) \rightarrow \neg \exists w \ S(w))$

... which is what you did in the first option.

I do note that you did not get that one all the way in prenex normal form though, so you need to take a few more steps:

$\neg \forall x \neg \forall y (Q(x,y) \rightarrow \neg \exists w \ S(w))=$

$\exists x \forall y (Q(x,y) \rightarrow \forall w \ \neg  S(w))=$

$\exists x \forall y \forall w (Q(x,y) \rightarrow  \ \neg  S(w))$

Comment: Just to be clear, since second term is different, I believe I can change it with an y in the first question?

∀x¬∃xQ(x,x) ∨ ∃xS(x)  = ¬∃xQ(x,x) ∨ ∃yS(y)

Comment: @b.y That is Correct!